# CSS Border Color: How to set bottom border color?

Tags: html, css, border

Current result: bottom border is colored gray

Desired result: all borders are white

Problem: border-color is set to white in the CSS

```css
.zoom {
  border-width: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
  background: white;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="zoom">???</button>
```

Comment: Hint: the default `border-style` for buttons is `outset`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the `border-style` as `solid` explicitly for it to work. The gray border that you see at the bottom is because of the default UA styling which I is `border-style: outset`.

As noted by [Marcos Pérez Gude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035890/marcos-p%C3%A9rez-gude) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749510/css-border-color-how-to-set-bottom-border-color/34749571#comment57244840_34749571) the default `border-style`  for buttons is `outset` and that for `input` and `textarea` elements is `inset`.

```css
.zoom {
  border-width: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
  background: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<button class="zoom">???</button>
```

**Screeshot of UA Stylesheet Value:**

[image]

Comment: `outset` is default value for buttons since before chrome exists. And `inset` for text inputs or textareas :)

Comment: Just asking - what is the expected result of running your code snippet.

Comment: I just figured that out, was thinking why!? I guess OP just want to make the button slightly taller but without any visual notice.

Comment: @Pangloss: Oh sorry :D Or maybe they are trying to get it on a page with image or other colored background.

Comment: Agreed, but use padding or height would a better choice, anyway not related to the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your CSS

```
border-style: solid;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Harry highlighted : You need to specify the style of the border in order to change the default.

you can also use an easier-to-remember code like this :

```
.zoom {
border-top:3px solid white;
border-bottom:3px solid white;
background-color:white;
}
```

`<button class="zoom">???</button>`

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, you can use **[border utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/#border)** to add or remove an element’s borders.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="border-0 bg-white">???</button>
```